# PHP: Error in sql but no error is given

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem with this function when the fetch is executed, but no error is given even in error_log.

The output is ": -> " (because none of the three methods have returned any error)

```
$appBD = new mysqli($hostApp, $userApp, $passApp, $dbApp);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

$saltLogin = 'My_salt';
  ...
  ...
  ...


function isValidToken($token)
{
    if(!isset($token) || $token==-1)
                 return false;

     global $saltLogin;
     global $appBD;

     $query = "SELECT 1 FROM Test WHERE Cont is null and Pass is not null and birthDate is not null and SHA2(concat(Cont,Pass,date_format(birthDate, '%d%m%Y'),?), 512) = ?";

             if( !$stmt = $appBD->prepare($query) ){ throw new Exception($appBD->error); }
             if( !$stmt->bind_param("ss",  $saltLogin, $token) ){ throw new Exception($stmt->error); }//i:integer, s:string, d:double, b:blob
             if( !$stmt->execute() ){ throw new Exception($stmt->error); }
             if( !$stmt->bind_result( $exists ) ){ $stmt->close(); throw new Exception($stmt->error); }
             if( !$stmt->fetch() ){ $error = $appBD->error.': '.$stmt->error.' -> '.$stmt->errno; $stmt->close(); throw new Exception($error); }
             if( !$stmt->close() ){ throw new Exception($stmt->error); }
     return $exists;
}
```

Comment: SELECT 1? You've got a column called 1?

Comment: You have a column in your DB with the name 1?

Comment: Sidenote: If your column's date is DATETIME, then "d-m-Y" won't work. It relies on being "Y-m-d". Could be a contributing factor.

Comment: You should add this to the top of your script: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. Now mysqli will throw exceptions so you don't have to check and throw them manually. They'll have more information too.

Comment: instead of SELECT 1, you probaply want to do SELECT * FROM blablabla (at the end) LIMIT 1

Comment: do what @jeroen says, but can you run that query manually?  Does it run properly or throw an error in phpmyadmin or another DBA program.

Comment: you really should just turn on exception mode in mysqli, instead of manually testing/throwing on every statement...

Comment: By the way, the `SELECT 1` should work without any problems, but will just return the number `1` if your condition is met. Which could do for a check to see if something exists...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the problem:

fetch can return true, false (if error) o null if it doesn't find data.

As I had changed the way to calculate the hash, the condition was false and returned null that it was evaluated as false.

So I changed the code to:

```
if($stmt->fetch() === false){...}
```

Thanks Jeroen for your help.

PD: "Select 1... where " return 1 if the condition is true or nothing otherwise. It's a way to check if the credentials are right.
The "1" was only for testing, in fact it returns the user code.

Comment: This is exactly same as `!$stmt->fetch()`. Anyway, i think you need to use `select count(*)`